# Loop through dictionary and change values

Tags: python

Lets say I have a dictionary with names and grades:

```
{"Tom" : 65, "Bob" : 90, "John" : 80...}
```

and I want to take all the values in the dictionary and add 10% to each:

```
{"Tom" : 71.5, "Bob" : 99, "John" : 88...}
```

How can I do it through all the values in the dictionary?

Answer (score 8):

Dict comprehension:

```
mydict = {key:value*1.10 for key, value in mydict.items()}
```

Pre 2.7 :

```
mydict = dict(((key, value*1.10) for key, value in mydict.items()))
```

Answer (score 5):

You didn't ask for your dict to be replaced by a new one. The following code updates your existing dictionary. It uses basic looping techniques, which are as handy to know as well as comprehensions.

```
for name in grade_dict:
    grade_dict[name] *= 1.1
```

Answer (score 4):

For python of version less than 2.7 you can use this:

```
result = dict((k, 1.1 * v) for k, v in h.items())
```

and for python 2.7 or higher you just do:

```
result = { k: 1.1 * v for k, v in h.items() }
```

Comment: nice one, how would you iterate v for a dictionnary with multiples values per input (in python 2.7), like - Bob : (123,465,789) ? thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
{i:1.1*j for i,j in my_dict.items()}
```